# Knockout bad performance in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have a set of nested data which looks something like this:

```
group
  task
    action
    action
    action
  task
    action
    action
    action
group
  task
    action
    action
    action
  task
    action
    action
    action
```

So basically nesting inside of nesting. The issue that I'm running into is that in IE (all) it hangs for about 10 seconds after the javascript has finished processing while it is trying to put everything into the DOM.

I've put together a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tizupuyoto/1/edit) demonstrating my issues. I would suggest you open in Chrome first then in IE to see the difference. As you can see I'm using the mapping plugin to convert the js object into the proper view models. I'm not sure if this would be a potential issue if it's trying to

Does anyone have suggestions as how to help out IE to render everything faster?

Thanks - Matt

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you getting any console errors in IE that don't display in other browsers (Safari, Firefox, etc.)?

Comment: I do not ( other than missing mapping files :) )

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be to open up the HTML file in Internet Explorer, go to the Debugging tools (F12), and select the Profiler.  If you start the Profiler and run the code, you can see the functions it's hanging up on.  When I ran the IE Profiler in JSBin, it said that `appendChild()` and `innerHTML()` were the biggest suspects.  However, it's difficult for me to tell you how to adjust these in your code without a pretty good understanding of what's going on in the project.